# UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer: top and bottom edges

Tags: ios, iphone, uigesturerecognizer

Is this possible to make **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer** handle events from **top** (or **bottom**) edge?

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userDidPan:)];
gestureRecognizer.edges = UIRectEdgeTop;  // UIRectEdgeBottom
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
```

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The status bar must be hidden so it works. In your `UIViewController`, override 
`(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden()` and return YES.

However in ios8 (didn't test in ios7). I've got some issues with the bottom gesture not recognized when the device orientation is Landscape Left (and the top gesture is not recognized when the device orientation is Landscape right). I'm investigating but looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Thank you, surprisingly it works for both edges. I'm not fully satisfied because I have to get rid of status bar. But if it's the only way, what could I do...

Comment: I'll accept this answer in few days, if nobody's suggested anything better.

Comment: If you really want to have the status bar, I believe you have to do your own touch event tracking system (using touchBegan,etc...).

Answer (score 3):

Top and Bottom Edge Gestures trigger 20 Pixels from the screen Edge.

By default the status bar is Visible and takes the top 20 pixels space so you must hide the status bar to use these (top / bot) UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizers, or else  the delegate does Not get called.

Step1:

[image]

Step 2:

Add below code:

ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];

 UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *topEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTopEdgeGesture:)];
topEdgeGesture.edges = UIRectEdgeTop; //UIRectEdgeBottom
topEdgeGesture.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:topEdgeGesture];




  }
  - (BOOL) prefersStatusBarHidden
  {
  return YES;
  }

   - (void)handleTopEdgeGesture:(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
   {
    NSLog(@"TOP");
   }
```

**Swift:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()


    var edgeGesture : UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer = UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:"handleTopEdgeGesture:")
    edgeGesture.edges = UIRectEdge.Top
    edgeGesture.delegate = self
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(edgeGesture)

}


func handleTopEdgeGesture(gesture:UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer)
{
    println("TOP")
}


override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool
{
    return true
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: This is the same idea that you can find in Pierre's answer. But with typos and details I didn't ask about.

Comment: I already Know about this.Past few months before Already i faced this issue. If this is using for you, you will use it else leave this other peoples will use this