# Swipe down not getting fire the event in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am trying to capture gesture for 4 directions I put different functions for all directions, **left to right** and **right to left** is working well but swipe down is not firing

```
    var topTo = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "topToDownSwipeDidFire")

    topTo.direction = .down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(topTo)
```

So the function is not getting fired.

Comment: **You can check this link:** [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25571538/uiscreenedgepangesturerecognizer-top-and-bottom-edges)

Comment: change method to "topToDownSwipeDidFire:", and than implement this method like this "topToDownSwipeDidFire(_ sender: Any)"